# console.log(req.body) in backend not appearing in console + backend correction

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When the "Follow user" button is clicked (in Frienddetail component) the addPeopleFollow function is invoked. With this function I want to store the id of the user clicked (the one you are trying to follow) in the friends Array property of the user that is logged in/clicked on my database.

My database has a user collection with all users in with per user this:

```
_id:5eff397b70d78284c8c45186
friends:Array
username:"charlestryingout"
password:"$2b$10$CYMyPx10gk0jO5XoazcrSO32Ng37qoyU6uXkkeaswQ5KWm7k7ooym"
__v:0
```

For example: if user with `id = 5eff397b70d78284c8c45186` clicks the other user to follow with `id = 5eff397b70d78284c8c45187`, then I would want to have this as a result in my database:

```
_id:5eff397b70d78284c8c45186
friends:Array[5eff397b70d78284c8c45187]
username:"charlestryingout"
password:"$2b$10$CYMyPx10gk0jO5XoazcrSO32Ng37qoyU6uXkkeaswQ5KWm7k7ooym"
__v:0
```

**My questions:**

1. How come that the `console.log(req.body)` in the start of my backend part is not appearing in the console? Can I conclude that the request doesn't arrive in the backend? What is then the issue in my frontend?
2. Can someone help me writing the backend (first version below)?

Could you please write out the full code?
I am using Node/Mongoose/MongoDB/React.

---

**Frontend**

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import './Friends.css'
import Axios from 'axios'
import Frienddetail from '../components/Frienddetail'
import InnerCircleDetail from '../components/InnerCircleDetail'
// import PeopleYouFollow from '../components/PeopleYouFollow'
import { getUser } from '../utils/auth'
import qs from "qs"

class Friendsfollowers extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

    this.state = {
        friends: [],
        searchFriends: [],
        innerCircle: []      
    }
    
    this.searchFriends=this.searchFriends.bind(this)
    this.addToInnerCircle=this.addToInnerCircle.bind(this)
    this.deleteFromInnerCircle=this.deleteFromInnerCircle.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount(){ 
    Axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/friends`,
        withCredentials: true       
    })
    .then(response =>{
        console.log(response)
        let friendslist = response.data // eslint-disable-next-line
        let friendslistupdate = friendslist.filter(friend => {
            if(friend.username){
                if(friend.username !== getUser().username){
                    return true
                }
            }
        })
        this.setState({
            friends: friendslistupdate,
            searchFriends: friendslistupdate
        })
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        console.log("Charles made an error when retrieving all friends: ",error)
    })
}

addPeopleFollow(idpeopleyoufollow){
    Axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/friends`,
        data: qs.stringify(idpeopleyoufollow),
        headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
        withCredentials: true
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(idpeopleyoufollow)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response)
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <DefaultLayout>
            <div className="friendsboxes" >
                {
                    this.state.searchFriends.map(friend =>
                        <div key={friend._id}>
                            <Frienddetail 
                                key={friend._id}
                                id={friend._id}
                                username={friend.username}
                                location={friend.location}
                                innerCircle={this.addToInnerCircle}
                                peopleFollow={this.addPeopleFollow}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )   
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

**Usermodel**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    location: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    friends: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    error: String
})

const User = mongoose.model("users",userSchema)

module.exports = User;
```

---

**Backend**

```
// add peopleYouFollow
router.post("/friends", (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  let iduser = getUser()._id 
  console.log(iduser)
  User
  .findByIdAndUpdate({_id:iduser},{$push:{friends:req.body._id}})
  .then((response) => {
    res.json(response)
    console.log("thisishappening")
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

your request is not arriving at the backend. Please make sure your URL set in {process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE} is fine.
you can check if it is right by chechking in browser